# Why was my question downvoted and closed for being off topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, meta

I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404590/what-was-the-fastest-time-for-someone-on-stack-overflow-to-be-blocked) which was downvoted straight away and closed.

For less 10k reputation points:

[image]

I'm not sure why it was downvoted, nor why it was closed as "off-topic."

Stack Overflow's help pages on [closed reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions) states that:

- **Off-topic because…** - each community decides which specific topics are and are not allowed on their site. You can see this list of off-topic subjects for this site by viewing this help center article.

> This question doesn’t appear to be on-topic for this site.

Meta Stack Overflow doesn't have a direct list of what is on topic or not. Instead, it redirects to Stack Overflow's *[What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)*

I think that my question was perfectly on topic. I asked what was the fastest time for a user to get blocked. Meta Stack Overflow is, after all, supposed to be about Stack Overflow. And if this is off topic, why should *[What are the most upvoted/downvoted questions and answers on the sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11017/what-are-the-most-upvoted-downvoted-questions-and-answers-on-the-sites)* be on topic?

In the comments, some notable comments were:

> I've personally deleted spammers' accounts within 5 seconds of the spam being posted. I think that's sufficiently fast. I don't see how hard numbers would be any more useful to you. What problem are you actually trying to solve? - Cody Gray

The same could be said for the "most upvoted/downvoted" question. It's not trying to solve anything, and it wouldn't usually be considered useful.

Comment: It was likely downvoted because some users didn't consider it useful, as it says in the downvote tooltip.

Comment: Did you read the actual text in the blue box? The part that says: *"This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail."*

Comment: @yivi You have a point. I'm confused though, how would anyone consider what the most upvoted answer is useful?

Comment: Topicality is not determined by the existence of other questions in the corpus, and *especially* not questions on other sites.

Comment: Older questions are usually not good examples of what is currently on- or off-topic as policies change over time. The question you link to is not even on MSO.

Comment: Knowing the answer considered to be the most useful by the community is useful. Knowing the name of a deleted account, not so much.

Comment: So you know that "It's not trying to solve anything, and it *wouldn't usually be considered useful*." and yet asking why the post go downvotes? What other votes you expect on question that is not useful?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Well then why isn't the "most upvoted/downvoted" question downvoted, and what's the difference?

Comment: For the record, your question has been undeleted. It is still currently closed.

Answer (score 23):

It was not closed as off-topic. It was closed as:

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail.

while I was pondering on what reason to pick. Once closed I kicked delete voting into motion the first time. I'm glad to see familiar names as my fellow delete voters. And later I delete voted it a second time. Sometimes delete votes won't stick.

The answer to your question has no value for you, for the community or future visitors. The answer to your question could have been

> *user985757* was deleted 4.567 seconds after being created.

What would we learn from that? That 4.5 seconds is too slow and mods need to do better? That user985757 needs a  prize/swag? You want their contact info to pay them a house visit? Is deleting accounts a competition?

If you're asking "out of curiosity" then you're better off in a chat room that entertains the same curiosity.

You also state as a reaction to the comment that Cody left:

> The same could be said for the "most upvoted/downvoted" question

No, that is not the same, by any means. It is extremely useful to examine and consider voting on posts. You can learn useful things like: What makes a good or bad post, How do votes come in over time, Are the votes reflecting usefulness and/or quality. The community and visitors can learn how our main quality control mechanism contributes to the success of the content, the community and the site we're on.

While Meta is about discussion, it doesn't mean we've thrown out all quality aspects of the Q/A model. Your "question" would thrive on a traditional forum, not here on Meta.

Worth reading: [How do I participate in Meta and not die trying?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44188/how-do-i-participate-in-meta-and-not-die-trying)

Comment: I see that you voted to delete the OP's question a second time, after it was undeleted. It seems to me that the question was edited in a way that addresses the concerns in your answer. All references to specific accounts have been removed from the question. Also, as I explained in my answer, how is someone supposed to know that a chat room would be better for these discussions, or even that such rooms exist? I believe a post on MSO directing users to the appropriate chat room/s would be useful. You haven't left a comment on that post, so I'm not sure why you chose to delete it the second time.

Comment: I don't see any way in which the edits address rene's concerns, @cigien. It's still asking for irrelevant statistics with no clear goal. I do disagree that these questions should be asked in chat rooms, since only a moderator would really know the answer, and it's not appropriate to push off-topic questions into chat rooms anyway as a matter of general principle.

Comment: @CodyGray I'm not sure what you mean by "*asking for irrelevant statistics with no clear goal*". Isn't just being curious about some statistics about the site enough? For example, I've seen positively received questions as recently as a month ago, asking how many different Winter Bash hats can be earned on the site (or something to that effect, I wasn't really paying attention). What was relevant about statistics like that? What was the clear goal there? It just looked to me like users found that interesting/fun. What's the real difference here?

Comment: I'm not trying to be facetious with that analogy; I really can't see a clear difference between these cases other than an argument that stats about deleted accounts are a lot less interesting/fun than stats about hats. Maybe, but that's pretty subjective. I for one find the former much more interesting/fun. Unless the community has decided to dictate what users should find interesting/fun, I see no reason why that question should be closed in its current form. If that question is not interesting/fun to some users they should downvoted, not vote to close and/or delete it.

Comment: *"Isn't just being curious about some statistics about the site enough?"* Of course not. Any more than just being curious about some aspect of a programming language is enough to make a question on-topic for Stack Overflow. Winter Bash was an event of general interest, so, yes, there were a lot of questions about it that were well-received due to that general interest. If you asked a question about it now, I don't think that question would be very well received. @cigien

Comment: @CodyGray Well, sure, just being curious is not enough, the question also needs to be of reasonable scope, and answerable, etc. The question seems to satisfy all of that. I simply meant that curiosity was enough, and that there doesn't need to be some broader goal or problem to solve (akin to [language-lawyer] questions on Main). Also, I was under the impression that account deletion, and processes related to that are of general interest (at any time of the year). There's even a [deleted-users] tag for such questions.

Comment: I don't see anything of general interest here, or even specific interest. That's precisely the point. The only possible answer that could be given to that question is, "The accounts of spammers and other users with no redeeming participation are often destroyed by moderators, often very quickly, but not necessarily." That's useless. The question is not answerable.

Comment: @CodyGray That looks like an answer to me. A poor answer, but certainly an answer. A better answer would perhaps describe how that came to be, i.e. why we even cared to create and actively maintain a system that aims to block accounts so soon. The answer could maybe give a brief summary of how at one point we didn't catch spam as fast as we do now, and the efforts that have been, and are still put, into improving that. I could certainly imagine a useful answer to that question. I definitely find the topic of catching spam extremely fascinating, and the OP's question ties very much into that.

Comment: I prefer to close questions that serve only to elicit poor answers, at least on Meta. The "better answer" you describe is [already a blog post written by ArtOfCode](https://stackoverflow.blog/2020/06/25/how-does-spam-protection-work-on-stack-exchange/). @cigien

Comment: @CodyGray Oh, this is quite different than deciding whether to close on Main, i.e. not judging the question based on potential answers, and disregarding whether answers might exist on external sites. But I'm willing to defer to your judgement about such questions on Meta, I'm only just starting to learn how it works here. If you're confident that the question would only lead to poor answers, then I guess I won't argue for undeleting/reopening it.

Answer (score 2):

The stated close reason in the banner text says

> This question does not appear to seek input and discussion from the community. If you have encountered a problem on one of our sites, please describe it in detail.

Your question was likely closed and deleted because you asked about *which user's account was blocked the fastest*. Phrased this way, the question is off-topic for the above reason. [rene's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/404593) goes into further detail about those reasons quite nicely, so I don't have anything to add to that here.

---

On the other hand, if your question solely focused on "How fast do accounts get blocked?", that would be on-topic in my opinion. It's looking for clarification on how a particular aspect of Stack Overflow works, and I think it's useful to have such a question that users can look up. The answers to your question could be quite interesting as well, and I suspect most users don't know anything about the systems in place with regards to this. Consider this part of a [comment by Makyen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404590/what-was-the-fastest-time-for-someone-on-stack-overflow-to-be-blocked#comment820161_404590) to your question

> ... it's quite likely there have been multiple times where the process of registering has been in a race condition with the deletion/destruction process.

This is very interesting, to me at least, and until quite recently I was unaware of this, or even the existence of systems that allow for this. I think a useful answer could be provided that expands upon the working and/or intent of these systems.

Of course, the systems in place might be of a nature that prevents discussion of too many details of their inner workings, and it might be better to discuss these details in chat rooms that are dedicated to such things. But that would be quite a useful answer as well; perhaps something like this hypothetical answer

> Accounts get deleted *very* fast. Like *really* fast. So fast, we can't reasonably measure those timings. If you want to know more about how and why this happens, please bring this up in chat rooms where you can discuss these things further. [links/to/relevant/chatrooms]

Until relatively recently, I was unaware that such chat rooms even existed, and I think knowing where to go for these things, or even knowing that such resources exist, would be quite useful.

---

Given this, I have taken the liberty of editing your question to focus on the time-frame in which accounts get deleted, and removed all requests to know the identity of such accounts. I have also voted to undelete and reopen the question.

---

In this Meta, you've also asked why your question was *downvoted*. There are *many* possible reasons for this. However, there is no way to know why users downvoted your question unless they choose to explain, and they are not obliged to do so. As such, I'm not going to address that part of your question, as it would be purely speculation.

Comment: Glad I read this answer. I didn’t notice that you edited it. I saw the undelete and reopen votes and was ready to vote to close the question again as soon as it was reopened. I voted to undelete and reopen.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Oh, that's a good point, other users may not notice that the question was edited, and might close it based on their recollection of the post in it's original form. I'll add a comment on the original post if it's reopened, pointing them here. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: If what you've edited the other question into is something in which you're interested, then it seems like it might have been better to just create a new question to ask that, rather than substantially changing a closed and deleted question which is already heavily downvoted. It's not clear to me that the OP was all that interested in the absolute number, rather than which user/account it was which was deleted/destroyed the fastest. Thus, I'm not sure if the edits retained the OP's intent. OTOH, at this point, given that the question has been again deleted, it's not really viable to repost.

Comment: @Makyen Yes, I was definitely concerned that my edits were changing the OP's intent. I thought about it for a while, and concluded that the edits didn't cross the line in that regard. I took into consideration the fact that as a new user, the OP probably didn't realize that their question would have been fine if they just didn't mention the *deleted user account*.

Comment: After all, from the OP's POV, there must have been an account that was deleted the fastest, and there must have been a user at the end of that account, and hence the phrasing of their question. It's possible that I'm reading too much into that, and the OP is *only* interested in knowing the identity of the deleted account. That would certainly be changing the intent, and would make my edits unacceptable. If you feel strongly that that's the case, that's fine. I trust your judgement in these matters, and I won't push for reopening any further.

Comment: While I find this topic interesting, I happen to know of other ways of obtaining this information, and so I won't be posting that question myself. My goal with this answer and the edits was to try and see what it takes to reopen a Meta that was closed and deleted, where the OP then took the effort of actually posting another Meta looking for feedback (I've recently learned that users believe this to be an uphill battle, usually insurmountably so). BTW, I'm not sure I understand the last statement regarding viability of reposting. What do you mean by that exactly?

Comment: The last sentence was based on the fact that there's now a question along the lines of what you wanted which has been deleted in that form. In general, we discourage reposting already existing questions which have been deleted. I'm not going to go so far as to say "don't", just that the current situation is a lot closer to being something I'd be concerned over if a new question was posted than I would have been if you'd just started with posting a new question without having edited the one which this question is asking about. Overall, I'm on the fence about the situation.

Comment: @Makyen Ah, I see what you meant with the last sentence, thanks for the clarification. No, I have no interest in posting that same question myself. My intent with this answer and the edits on the original, is based on recent discussions in the [Ministry](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92764) suggesting that deleted Meta questions rarely, if ever, have the chance to be reopened/undeleted. Once this Meta was posted about a recently deleted question, it occurred to me that the original question could indeed be salvaged, and this is my attempt at doing that.

Comment: If overall you're on the fence about the situation, I think I'll keep responding to feedback from other users, and continue suggesting that the original question should be reopened and undeleted (with my reasons fr why they should do so, of course). Users can weigh in and/or cast votes according to how they feel about the situation, and the post will get reopened, or not, as the community feels appropriate.